# TPerlRegEx : How to match any character across multiple lines

Tags: regex, delphi

I am new to TPerlRegEx. Have a problem to match data from the data block due to some data have additional line is created randomly by the system.

Data

```
Opt: 
<NVR IP: 192.168.2.163>
<SRC IP: 192.168.2.123>
<TYPE: 5>
<INPUT: 2>


<Alarm ID:66

 Time:  29/07/2010 12:18:12 PM
 State: 1
 Assigned User: 0
 Assigned Time: 01/01/1970 8:00:00 AM
 Ack Time:  01/01/1970 8:00:00 AM>

<Alarm ID:67
 Time:  29/07/2010 3:11:07 PM
 State: 1
 Assigned User: 0
 Assigned Time: 01/01/1970 8:00:00 AM
 Ack Time:  01/01/1970 8:00:00 AM>

<Alarm ID:68
 Time:  29/07/2010 3:11:08 PM
 State: 1
 Assigned User: 0
 Assigned Time: 01/01/1970 8:00:00 AM
 Ack Time:  01/01/1970 8:00:00 AM>

Alarms got successfully
```

Here is my regular expression which can only match alarm 67 and 68. Alarm 66 has a additional line below and this line is randomly appear within the data block.

```
<Alarm\x20ID:.*?\r\n\t.*?\r\n\t.*?\r\n\t.*?\r\n\t.*?\r\n\t.*?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Alarm\x20ID:.*?\r+\n+\t*.*?\r+\n+\t*.*?\r+\n+\t*.*?\r+\n+\t*.*?\r+\n+\t*.*?>
```

or perhaps better

```
<Alarm\x20ID:.*?(\r\n)+\t*.*?(\r\n)+\t*.*?(\r\n)+\t*.*?(\r\n)+\t*.*?(\r\n)+\t*.*?>
```

Comment: Kim, I've edited to remove your signature block. The use of signatures is specifically against site guidelines (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Your name and a link to your user profile appears with every post here, and you can put company information and a URL to your web site in your profile. Thanks. :)